# pandas group by first column values and find maximum of remaining columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
  
country = ['US', 'US', 'US', 'UK', 'UK', 'Canada', 'Canada', "Mexico"]
rating =  [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 0, 1]
count = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]  

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(country,rating, count)), columns =['country', 'rating', 'count'])
```

which results to the following dataframe

```
    country rating  count
0   US         0    1
1   US         2    2
2   US         1    3
3   UK         4    1
4   UK         3    2
5   Canada     1    1
6   Canada     0    2
7   Mexico     1    1
```

What I want to do is to group by the first column values and for the respective groups find the maximum of the second and third columns. So the output dataframe would be the following:

```
    country rating  count
0   US         2    3
1   UK         4    2
2   Canada     1    2
3   Mexico     1    1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function.

```
df.groupby(['country']).max()
         rating  count
country               
Canada        1      2
Mexico        1      1
UK            4      2
US            2      3
```

If you want your index not to be the country names, you can reset it.

```py
new_df = df.groupby(['country']).max()
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
  country  rating  count
0  Canada       1      2
1  Mexico       1      1
2      UK       4      2
3      US       2      3
```

##### Edit

Thanks [@Henry Ecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker) for pointing out, that grupby without country name index can be obtained by following line:

```
df.groupby(['country'], as_index=False).max()
```

Comment: Can actually do -> `df.groupby(['country'], as_index=False).max()` instead of the reset_index after.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`GroupBy.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html?highlight=max#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max)

```
df.groupby("country").max()
```

```
         rating  count
country
Canada        1      2
Mexico        1      1
UK            4      2
US            2      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and `agg` to keep the highest value for each columns:

```
>>> df.groupby('country').agg({'rating': max, 'count': max}).reset_index()

  country  rating  count
0  Canada       1      2
1  Mexico       1      1
2      UK       4      2
3      US       2      3
```

My answer is a more general case than other answers because if you want the max of one column and the min of another column, you can with `agg`.